# How to add a button in top-left header in a WPF Datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

[image]

I have a DataGrid with row headers enabled. I need to place a button in top-left corner (Marked as 'X'). The purpose is of this button to add a new Row in DataGrid.

Note:
If i'm correct, in WinForms it's called [TopLeftHeaderCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.topleftheadercell(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: share some of  your xaml you have done